# Blazor Server реконнект на другой веб-сервер при отключении текущего

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

Имеется веб-приложение Blazor Server и список адресов веб-серверов. Как при выключении/падении текущего веб-сервера переключиться на любой активный веб-сервер из списка?

Comment: точно так же как подключаетесь к текущему серверу, только с другим адресом.

Comment: @aepot забыл уточнить, это переподключение должно происходить автоматически при падении/выключении текущего веб-сервера

Comment: Разбейте задачу на части, например сначала разберитесть, как понять что текущий сервер - всё.